# Desabilitar um botão em um conjunto de botões (PHP JQuery)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Fiz um script em *JQuery* para a instalação de softwares por mei
o de um script *PHP*.

O *JQuery* pega a requisição de instalação por meio de um um botão criado em um script *HTML* e chama o *PHP* que faz a instalação pelo `shell_exec`.

Essa parte funciona perfeitamente, agora eu precisava fazer uma verificação se o software já está instalado na máquina e desabilitar apenas o botão referente ao software instalado.

O que eu tinha pensado era verificar por meio de um script *PHP* e mandar por meio de um *JSON* para um script *JQuery* os softwares instalados para que esse script desabilite o botão referente aos mesmos, porém não estou sabendo como fazer isso, se alguém puder ajudar agradeço.

Seguem os códigos do *JQuery* e do *PHP* que fazem a instalação.

```
//Jquery

function instalaSoftware(software){
    console.log(software.data.software)  
    $.get("instalaSoftware.php?software="+software.data.software)
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#soft1").click({software:'soft-1'},instalaSoftware)
    $("#soft2").click({software:'soft-2'},instalaSoftware)
    $("#soft3").click({software:'soft-3'},instalaSoftware)
    $("#soft4").click({software:'soft-4'},instalaSoftware)
    $("#soft5").click({software:'soft-5'},instalaSoftware)
}
```

//Script PHP (instalaSoftware)

```
<?php
$softwareId = $_GET ["software"];

if($softwareId != ""){
    $up = shell_exec("sudo apt-get update");
    $softwareInstall = shell_exec("sudo apt-get -y --force-yes install $softwareId");
    echo $softwareInstall;
}
?>
```

Comment: Removi a resposta temporariamente. Seu último comentário ficou assim: "_Dessa forma não deu certo pra forma que eu preciso. Eu queria em um novo script PHP conseguir verificar se o software está instalado na pasta com um comando tipo:_"... ficou incompleto no final.

Comment: Eu mandei sem terminar. Desculpe. Então, a solução que tu me mandou está desabilitando todos os botões. Ele não está conseguindo ler o que está contido no JSON parece, mas também não sei se meu código PHP que produz ele está certo, ele está como se segue:  $softName = $_GET["software"];

for ($softName = 0; $softName < 4; $softName++) {
    $softFind = shell_exec("cd /var/www").shell_exec("ls | grep $softName");
    return $softFind;  
};
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($softFind);

Comment: Certo. A solução que coloquei deveria desabilitar apenas o botão com a id passada na função após o retorno do Ajax $.get. Neste caso, se vc atualizar a página, o botão voltará ao normal.

Comment: Teria como me explicar como funciona a .repleace()? Não entendi direito a função dela, ainda sou novata em script.

Comment: O valor de `software.data.software` é `soft-1`... a id do botão é `soft1`, logo teria que eliminar esse hífen `-` pra ficar igual a id do botão. O replace faz isso, substitui o hífen por vazio: `string.replace('-', '');`...

Comment: Me parece que o problema é que ele não consegue ler os softwares instalados que estão contidos no arquivo JSON para desabilitar apenas os botões referentes aos softwares já instalados. Não sei como fazer pra ele ler o JSON e comparar as ids dos botões com as ids que estão no arquivo, pra aí verificar se são as mesmas e desabilitar os botões referentes. Isso considerando que meu script PHP está certo...

Comment: Mas o JSON está vindo certo? De onde ele está vindo?

Comment: Sim, está. Ele vem de um script PHP que eu chamo pelo url do ajax.

Comment: Então já é outro caso. Na questão do clique era o que coloquei mesmo. Vc quer desabilitar os botões no carregamento da página usando esse JSON que vc se refere? Qual é o Ajax que recebe esse JSON?

Comment: Isso. No carregamento da página ele verifica quais softwares estão instalados e desabilita os botões referentes a eles pra evitar que o usuário tente instalar o mesmo software duas vezes. Eu fiz um script JS separado para fazer o processo de recepção do JSON e desabilitação dos botões.                                          
  $.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  dataType: "JSON",
  url: "verificaSoftware.php",
  success: function verificaSoftware(software){
    //cod de comparação do JSON com a id dos botões
  }
});